# React + google sheets api, how to access data and display my results

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm building an react app that reads my google sheets file and displays to me my data.

But whenever I import the data from my sheet it comes into an array that I cant manage to access and get the data.

[image: the output is credenciados, but I want to display the results of the JSONn inside of this element]

I want to show the data inside of the `credenciados` like the image bellow
[image]

This is my current code.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import useGoogleSheets from 'use-google-sheets';

    const App = () => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useGoogleSheets({
    apiKey: 'mykey',
    sheetId: 'myid',
    sheetsOptions: [{ id: 'credenciados' }]
     });

     const sheetData = Array.from(data);
     console.log(sheetData);
     return (
       <ul>
         {sheetData.map((data) => (
        <li key={data.id}>
          {data.id} {data.razao}
        </li>
      ))}
       </ul>
      );
      };
     export default App;
```

That's the final result that I got after hours of trying. I've read google sheets documentation, react documentation but didn't manage to find the solution

Comment: Please share a copy or sample of your sheet, whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{sheetData.data.map((data) => (
    <li key={data.id}>
      {data.id} {data.razao}
    </li>
  ))}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell the difference between this and the OP's original code.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I need access to your data in order to help you better, but, It seems that what's happenning is that

It seems that `sheetData` is an array of objects with the key `data`, that means that you should get the data key first (your destructured object you're calling data is not the same)

```js
{sheetData.map((el) => (
  <li key={el.data.id}>
    {el.data.id} {el.data.razao}
  </li>
))}
```

Another option could be to destructure the data element:

```js
{sheetData.map(({ data }) => (
  <li key={data.id}>
    {data.id} {data.razao}
  </li>
))}
```